# Custom laravel validator for array element?

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I want to customize my laravel validator.

As of now I have multiple checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="prodRelatedID[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="prodRelatedID[]" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" name="prodRelatedID[]" value="189">
```

and in my `Request.php` file I have this

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'prodTitle' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'prodDesc' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'attachment' => ['image','mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg','max:2048'],
        'prodSize' => ['required','string','max:255'],
        'prodCategory' => ['required','string','max:255'],
        'prodPrice' =>  ['required','regex:/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$/'],
        'prodRelatedID' => ['required'],
        'prodRelatedID.*' => ['accepted'],
    ];
}
```

Now how can I customize the error message like for the `prodRelatedID` ?

If user didnt check the checkboxes this will return something like this

`Please choose atleast 1 product related`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this:

1  Add an array of messages to match your rules, and send it to the validate method

```
$messages = [
    'prodRelatedId.required' => 'Please choose at least 1 product related'
]

$request->validate($rules, $messages);
```

Or 2, the cleaner one, that I prefer, is to edit the

```
resources\assets\lang\en\validation.php
```

and modify the "attributes" key at the end of the file and add your values there as so:

```
'attributes' => [
    'prodRelatedID' => 'product related'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using form request then you can just overwrite the messages method:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'prodRelatedID.required' => 'Please choose at least 1 product related',
    ];
}
```